# Link should direct user to web-site or to the mobile app depending on platform the user is on

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, deep-linking

Is there any way, through the html/css (email) code, to only put one link that identifies the device (i.e. desktop, Android, iOS) and depending on platform the user is on direct him to web-site or to the mobile app (Android, iOS).

diagram

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: [https://branch.io/app-store-urls](https://branch.io/app-store-urls) should create links for you that does all of that handling for you. You won't be able to open up the app unless you register it to handle deep linking. I suggest you implement [Branch](https://branch.io) to allow your app to handle deep linking.

Comment: If the task of re-directing user is not the primary purpose of your product, consider third party solutions that will do this for you. I am working in [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) team. Firebase Dynamic Links support all use cases you describing on the diagram.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot. Your comments have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the OS details using Javascript

`oscpuInfo = window.navigator.oscpu` will store this info into a string

```
function osInfo() { 
  alert(window.navigator.oscpu); 
}
// example result is: "Windows NT 6.0"
```

see [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage) for a nice answer on redirection by simulating an HTTP redirect